# Link Field code in MS Word and automatic numbering

Tags: ms-word, field

I have a document in Microsoft Word (2013 on Windows 8.1) with a numbered list (simple list numbering) from 1. to ~300. Within this same document, I used cross-references to refer to specific list elements by number.

In a separate Word document, I use the [{Link} field code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-Link-field-09422d50-cde0-4b77-bca7-6a8b8e2cddbd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) to refer to my list element using bookmarks.

However, when using the {Link} field Code, all numbering shows as "1.", and not the actual given number for the list element.

Is there a way to fix this occurence, short of [converting all the automatic numbering to text](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T010248_Converting_Automatic_Numbering_to_Manual_Numbering.html)?

Thanks for your insight,

Comment: You can't put bookmarks around automatic numbered lists. Therefore you won't be able to use a LINK or INCLUDETEXT field. What you can do: Use a SEQ field for your numbering, then add a bookmark around the SEQ field that you want to reference from the other document; in the other document you can then use an INCLUDETEXT field to include the bookmark text.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Dirk. For future documents, I'll definitely start with SEQ numbering and cross-referencing manually.

For now, this seems to work awkwardly, but well enough for my needs: 
{INCLUDETEXT "\\\\Path\\Document.docx" BookmarkName \!} [(note the \! switch)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-IncludeText-field-1c34d6d6-0de3-4b5c-916a-2ff950fb629e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)